# Targa Run-Length encoding

Tags: c++, c++11, compression, textures

I am currently trying to decompress targa (RGB24_RLE) image data.

My algorithm looks like this:

```
static constexpr size_t kPacketHeaderSize = sizeof(char);

        //http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/
        inline void DecompressRLE(unsigned int a_BytePerPixel, std::vector<CrByte>& a_In, std::vector<CrByte>& a_Out)
        {
            for (auto it = a_In.begin(); it != a_In.end();)
            {
                //Read packet header
                int header = *it & 0xFF;
                int count = (header & 0x7F) + 1;

                if ((header & 0x80) != 0) //packet type
                {
                    //For the run length packet, the header is followed by
                    //a single color value, which is assumed to be repeated
                    //the number of times specified in the header.

                    auto paStart = it + kPacketHeaderSize;
                    auto paEnd = paStart + a_BytePerPixel;

                    //Insert packets into output buffer
                    for (size_t pk = 0; pk < count; ++pk)
                    {
                        a_Out.insert(a_Out.end(), paStart, paEnd);
                    }

                    //Jump to next header
                    std::advance(it, kPacketHeaderSize + a_BytePerPixel);
                }
                else
                {
                    //For the raw packet, the header s followed by
                    //the number of color values specified in the header.

                    auto paStart = it + kPacketHeaderSize;
                    auto paEnd = paStart + count * a_BytePerPixel;

                    //Insert packets into output buffer
                    a_Out.insert(a_Out.end(), paStart, paEnd);

                    //Jump to next header
                    std::advance(it, kPacketHeaderSize + count * a_BytePerPixel);
                }
            }
        }
```

It is called here:

```
//Read compressed data
std::vector<CrByte> compressed(imageSize);
ifs.seekg(sizeof(Header), std::ifstream::beg);
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(compressed.data()), imageSize);

//Decompress
std::vector<CrByte> decompressed(imageSize);
DecompressRLE(bytePerPixel, compressed, decompressed);
```

`imageSize` is defined like this:

```
size_t imageSize = hd.width * hd.height * bytePerPixel
```

However, after DecompressRLE() finishes (which takes a **very long time** with 2048x2048 textures) decompressed is still empty/only contains zeros. Maybe I am missing somehting out.

`count` seems to be unreasonably high sometimes, which I think is abnormal.
`compressedSize` *should* be less than imageSize, otherwise it's not compressed. However, using `ifstream::tellg()` gives me wrong results.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at your variables in your debugger, you would see that `std::vector<CrByte> decompressed(imageSize);` declares a vector with `imageSize` elements in it.  In `DecompressRLE` you then insert at the end of that vector, causing it to grow.  This is why your decompressed image is full of zeros, and also why it takes so long (because the vector will be resized periodically).

What you want to do is reserve the space:

```
std::vector<CrByte> decompressed;
decompressed.reserve(imageSize);
```

Your compressed buffer looks like it is larger than the file content, so you're still decompressing past the end of the file.  The compressed file size should be in `Header`.  Use it.

Comment: Thanks! "The compressed file size should be in Header." what header do you mean? The targa header or run-length packet header?

Comment: @mutex36 The targa header.

Comment: According to [this specification](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/) there is no compressed size specified in the header? just width and height, which equals the width and height of the final, uncompressed image.

Comment: @mutex36 Then you need to rely on the file size (remember to subtract the size of `Header` from the compressed file size).